# 100% height absolute positioned divs with sticky footer

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've seen this question asked before, but not with an answer that works. I want a couple of absolutely positioned divs to expand to 100% of the full page length, and also a sticky footer.

This works perfectly well, *except* when the window height is less than the height of the content - i.e. vertical scrolling is required. When vertical scrolling is required, the absolutely positioned divs (and therefore their parents) are 100% of the visible area, not of the full page length. This leads to a gap showing.

I can get rid of the gap by removing

```
html, body {
height:100%;
}
```

from the code, but then of course the footer isn't at the bottom of the page.

You can see a cut down example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rickibarnes/8ra4djdw/

Can anyone tell me definitively, is this just not possible?

Note the reason I am making the divs absolutely positioned is to take them out of the document flow. and therefore make the .copy div overlay them. If anyone can think of a different way of doing this that will allow the height to work, I'd also be thrilled to hear it. This is the third different way I've tried to do this, and still no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I've got it working how I want to, and I'm posting the solution I've used in case it's of any help. It again uses position:absolute, but for actual positioning this time. I feel dirty :O

.pure-container goes to min-height, footer is absolutely positioned, and the overall parent of the main content, .sections, adds padding-bottom of the height of the footer so the footer never overlaps it.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rickibarnes/rrd8f11o/

```
.pure-container {
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}

footer {
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.sections {
    padding:0 0 20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/8ra4djdw/2/

Edited style for `.copy` and `.main`.

```css
html {
min-height:100%;
}

html, body {
height:100%;
}

body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
overflow-x:hidden;
}

* {
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.pure-container {
position:relative;
height:100%;
}

#preheader {
height:37px;
background-color:#CCC;
}

header {
width:20%;
height:calc(100% - 37px);
margin:0;
padding:20px 0;
background-color:#999;
position:absolute;
}

#main-nav {
margin:100px auto 0 auto;
}

.main {
width:100%;
height:calc(100% - 37px);
margin:0 auto;
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
align-content:space-between;
}

.sections {
width:100%;
/* display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap; */
height: calc(100% - 37px);
}

#slider {
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}

footer {
width:100%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.28);
z-index:16;
color:#FFF;
}

#slideshow {
width:100%;
height:calc(100% - 37px);
margin:0 0 0 20%;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
top:37px;
left:0;
order:2;
}

#slider {
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

.slideshow {
list-style:none;
z-index:1;
}

.slideshow li span {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  color:transparent;
  background:url(http://rickibarn.es/images/other/index-01.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  z-index:0;
}

.copy {
width:75%;
margin:100px 0 0 0;
position:relative;
left:calc(20% - 70px);
border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
z-index:15;
order:1;

height: calc(100% - 100px);
overflow: auto;
}

.copy h1, .copy p {
max-width:345px;
margin:0;
margin-left:calc(100% - 345px);
padding:25px 30px 10px 30px;
color:#FFF;
background-color:rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="pure-container">
  
<section id="preheader">
  Preheader
</section>

  
<header>
  <nav id="main-nav">
    <ul class="navlist">
      <li>menu</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
   </header>


<div class="main">

  <div class="sections">
  
  
    <section id="slideshow">
      <div id="slider">
        <ul class="slideshow">
          <li> <span>1/6</span> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    
    <section id="copy" class="copy">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      
      <div class="copy-para">
      <p>
      Aliquam malesuada turpis vitae hendrerit dapibus. Fusce nec ultricies augue, in pellentesque leo. Quisque aliquam ullamcorper tellus nec iaculis. Phasellus euismod aliquet volutpat. Nullam magna elit, euismod facilisis est eget, tempus semper nisl. 
      </p>
      
      <p>
      Mauris dapibus leo ut sagittis porta. Proin vitae eros sed ex aliquet cursus vel tristique lacus. Nunc ornare, tellus eget dignissim fringilla, mauris nisl vestibulum risus, id porttitor erat ligula sed diam. Duis non est libero. Nam vulputate erat non nulla eleifend.
      </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    
  
  </div>
    
    
    
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
  
    
</div>


  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, not quite what I'm looking for though. I'd still want the vertical scrolling to be on the whole page, not just the single element. Also for other reasons I do need .sections to be a flex element.